# $(document).ready(function() {...}) runs before plugin script loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, ready

I'm getting a JS error because my `$(function () {...})` handler is being fired seemingly before the prerequisite plugin script is loaded. Only happens in IE (testing in IE7).

I have some HTML in my `<head>` that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/org.wicketstuff.jwicket.JQuery/jquery-1.4.2-special.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" id="noConflict"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/
jQuery.noConflict();
/*-->]]>*/</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/com.csc.aims.wicket.components.collapsiblefieldset.CollapsibleFieldsetBehavior/jquery.collapsiblefieldset.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/com.csc.aims.wicket.components.collapsiblefieldset.CollapsibleFieldsetBehavior/jquery.collapsiblefieldset.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#collapse119').collapse({"iconClosedUrl":"../resources/img/white_plus","iconOpenUrl":"../resources/img/white_minus"});
});
</script>
```

So notice the sequence, according to the HTML code, is as follows:

1. jquery-1.4.2-special.js
2. jQuery.noConflict() call
3. jquery.collapsiblefieldset.js //defines $.fn.collapse
4. jQuery('#collapse119').collapse(...) is called

When this code runs in FF, everything works fine. When I test it in IE7 (or IE8 w/Compat. View: IE7 standards mode), I get a javascript error. The debugger shows me that jQuery.fn.collapse is undefined.

Using the IE8 developer tools, I try to look at jquery.collapsiblefieldset.js. I see the script in the list, but the tool tells me that I can't set a breakpoint because the script isn't loaded.

Why does the collapsiblefieldset.js not get loaded before my $() ready handler is run? Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using

```
$(function(){...});
```

which is synonym of

```
$(document).ready( function(){...} );
```

Instead, you might try

```
$(window).load( function(){...} );
```

which fires later in the page loading sequence.

Comment: Thank you! This seems promising; I'll try it out on Monday

Comment: I was mistaken to think that it was a timing issue. The errors I got were masking the actual problem, which was a syntax error in the external .js file in question. Assigning the command script to the window load event seems to have exposed the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of your scripts at the bottom of the page, right before the `</body>` tag.

If that doesn't fix it, move the scripts that do not appear to be loading in time back to the `<head>`, and leave the rest of the scripts at the bottom.

Comment: The web framework I'm using doesn't easily permit me to put it at the bottom of <body>. I changed it so that the collapsiblefieldset.js is in <head>, and the jQuery ready handler is down in the body, at the point where the widget is defined. This doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of other scripts that run on this page; the most expensive of which happen in $() ready handlers. Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to use the developer tools in IE8 to try and debug the Javascript code. http://coolwebdeveloper.com/2009/03/fantastic-new-javascript-debugging-tool-with-ie-8-and-its-list-of-features-hard-to-live-without/

Comment: I did use the IE8 debugger, as mentioned in the original post. =)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else suffering from this problem, it might be worth double checking that you don't have multiple references to jQuery. If you have plugins defined in the head, then they will get overridden by a second jQuery call in the body.